# Question about derivation of normal distribution properties

Tags: probability-theory

The normal distribution is given by the density

$$g_{\alpha,\sigma^2}(x) = (2 \pi \sigma^2)^{-1/2}  \exp\left(-\frac{(x-\alpha)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) $$

in the probability book of bauer it is claimed that for X distributed accoding to $g_{\alpha,\sigma^2}$ it holds

$$ \mathbb{E}(X) = \alpha \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbb{E}(X^2) = \sigma^2 + \alpha^2$$

In the book you will only find a proof for the case $\alpha = 0$ and $\sigma = 1$. The auther claims that the general case follows from the fact that for the map
$$ T(x):=\sigma x + \alpha $$
and the measure 
$$\nu_{\alpha,\sigma^2} := g_{\alpha,\sigma^2} \lambda^1$$ it holds
$$T(\nu_{0,1})=\nu_{\alpha,\sigma^2}.$$

Where $T(\nu) (A)= \nu(T^{-1}(A))$.

I agree with the equation above, but I do not see how the general case for any $\alpha$ and $\sigma$ follows from the standard normal distribution. Am I missing anything trivial?

Comment: Perhaps you should begin from the _general_ properties of expectation from which you can get $$E[\sigma Y + \alpha] = \sigma E[Y] + \alpha, \quad E[(\sigma Y + \alpha)^2] = \sigma^2E[Y^2] + 2\alpha\sigma E[Y] + \alpha^2$$ regardless of the distribution (of course, as long as $E[Y]$ and $E[Y^2]$ are defined). Then, apply this to the special case when $Y \sim g_{0,1^2}$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate yes thats correct. Short way of writing the long answer from below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the shortest way, but I think one can use
$$ \int f' dT(\nu) = \int f' \circ T d\nu.$$
Then, if $X$ is distributed accoring to $g_{\alpha,\sigma^2}$, one obtains
$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(X) &= \int x \, d\nu_{\alpha,\sigma^2}\\
&= \int x\, dT(\nu_{0,1})\\
&= \int T(x) \, d\nu_{0,1}\\
&= \int T(x) \, g_{0,1}(x) \, dx \\
&= \sigma \int x \, g_{0,1}(x) \, dx + \alpha \int  g_{0,1}(x) \, dx \\ 
&= \alpha\end{align*}$$
and

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(X^2) &= \int x^2 \, d\nu_{\alpha,\sigma^2}\\
&= \int x^2\, dT(\nu_{0,1})\\
&= \int T(x)^2 \, d\nu_{0,1}\\
&= \int T(x)^2 \, g_{0,1}(x) \, dx \\
&= \sigma^2 \int x^2 \, g_{0,1}(x) \, dx+ 2\sigma\alpha \int x \, g_{0,1}(x) + \alpha^2 \int  g_{0,1}(x) \, dx \\ 
&= \sigma^2 + \alpha^2\end{align*}$$

using $\int x^2 \, g_{0,1}(x) \,dx= \int g_{0,1}(x) \,dx=1$ and $\int x \, g_{0,1}(x) \,dx =0$.